# Extracting attachment from an attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

I have macros that save the attachments in a specific folder.
It works perfectly with the following code:
atmt.SaveAsFile

Some emails however contain an email attachment that contain the desired file.
How do i extract such a second-level attachment?

Comment: Have you tried saving the attached mail to disk then opening it in Outlook ?  You should then be able to save the attachments from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Thank you all for your suggestions. The following works:

```
For Each atmt In zMsg.Attachments 'Loop through attachments

    atmt.SaveAsFile DestPath & atmt.FileName
    Set zMsg2 = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(DestPath & atmt.FileName)

    For Each atmt2 In zMsg2.Attachments
        atmt2.SaveAsFile DestPath & atmt2.FileName
    Next
    Set zMsg2 = Nothing
    Kill DestPath & atmt.FileName
Next
```